# java regex Matcher extract text between matches

Tags: java, regex

Here's my input text

```
    1. INTRODUCTION
    This is a test document. This document lines can span multiple lines.
    This is another line.
    2. PROCESS
    This is a test process. This is another line.
    3. ANOTHER HEADING
    ...
```

I want to extract text between the main titles, 1,2,3 and so on. I am using this regular expression to match the titles - `^[ ]{0,2}?[0-9]{0,2}\\.(.*)$`

How do I extract text between matches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
\d+\. +[^\n]+\s*([\s\S]*?)(?=\s+\d+\. +|\z)
```

And grab captured group #1

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uG0cZ9/1)

Comment: can this not be done programmatically, using indexes from matches and then sub stringing the original text?

Comment: Sure, you can write a routine to go through the text line by line and do the parsing. I provided a regex solution since question was tagged as `regex`.

Comment: Could you possible give a java code solution for this?

Comment: Is this not working for you? Sorry, it is not a good practice to change the nature of question completely via comments. I suggest opening a new question for that and if this works then accept it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30869113/extract-text-between-matches-using-java - that's the java question.