# extract text between matches using java

Tags: java

Here's my input text

```
    1. INTRODUCTION
    This is a test document. This document lines can span multiple lines.
    This is another line.
    2. PROCESS
    This is a test process. This is another line.
    3. ANOTHER HEADING
    ...
```

I want to extract text between the main titles, 1,2,3 and so on. I am using this regular expression to match the titles - `^[ ]{0,2}?[0-9]{0,2}\\.(.*)$`

How do I extract text between matches?

**EDIT**

I tried using this code -

```
while(matcher.find()) {
}
```

if  I look ahead for the next match's starting index in this while loop, it will change the state of the Matcher. How do I get the text between using `String.substring`? I will need to the end of the current match and the beginning of the next match to do a substring.

Comment: Java has `Pattern` and `Matcher` classes for this.

Comment: You should ask a new question with all the details and reference the other one, rather than linking.

Comment: @Jay: How are you getting input text block in your code?

Comment: I am reading it from a doc.

Comment: `matcher.group(1)` will give you the text you want inside `while` loop.

Comment: @anubhava using the above regex, that would return the title, not the text between titles?

Comment: No check my demo: https://regex101.com/r/uG0cZ9/1 You will get text **between** the titles using `matcher.group(1)`

Comment: Yes, but that is if I use the regular expression that you are proposing. I am looking to use this regex ^[ ]{0,2}?[0-9]{0,2}\\.(.*)$ and get the text using substring. I am not sure if your regex will fail somewhere, which is why I am trying to avoid matching text inbetween as a group with your regex.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80677/discussion-between-jay-and-anubhava).

Comment: You do realize that one could post exactly the same answer as what was posted to your previous question, since the latest revision is identical except for the "EDIT" block, which only gives something you've tried, right? Explicitly state what solution you want and what you don't want. Although I personally would've recommended just posting a comment on your original question, editing it or adding a bounty saying you're looking for a solution different to the one already posted, rather than posting a new question.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I extract text between matches?

Do you mean between 1. INTRODUCTION and 2. PROCESS and so on?  If so, if the next line is not a "header" line, add the text to some buffer.  If it is a header, add the buffer to a running list and then clear the buffer.

Something like (in pseudo code)

```
List<String> content 
currentContent = ""
while line = readNextLine() 
   if not matched header
      currentContent += line
   else  
      // found new header, clear the content and add it to the list
      if currentContent != "" 
         content.add(currentContent)
         currentContent = ""
```

Edit: as one big string

```
// Split the lines by new lines
String[] bits = yourString.split("\\n");

String currentContent = "";    // Text between headers
List<String> content = new ArrayList<String>();       // Running list of text between headers

// Loop through each line
for (String bit : bits) {
    Matcher m = yourPattern.match(bit);
    if (m.matches()) {
       // Found a header
       if (currentContent.length() != 0) {
          content.add(currentContent);
          currentContent = "";
       }
    } else {
       // Not a header, just append the line
       currentContent += bit;
    }
}
```

Something like that would work.  I suppose you could do a complicated multi-line regex but this seems easier to me

Comment: I am not able to figure out how exactly this will work with the java API :(

Comment: How are you reading your text?  Line by line or as one big string?

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
    String text =
        " 1. INTRODUCTION\n"
        + " This is a test document. This document lines can span multiple lines.\n"
        + " This is another line.\n"
        + " 2. PROCESS\n"
        + " This is a test process. This is another line.\n"
        + " 3. ANOTHER HEADING\n";
    Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("^[ ]{0,2}?[0-9]{0,2}\\.(.*)$", Pattern.MULTILINE);
    Matcher m = pat.matcher(text);
    int start = 0;
    while (m.find()) {
        if (start < m.start()) {
            System.out.println("*** paragraphs:");
            System.out.println(text.substring(start, m.start()));
        }
        System.out.println("*** title:");
        System.out.println(m.group());
        start = m.end();
    }
```

The results are:

```
*** title:
 1. INTRODUCTION
*** paragraphs:

 This is a test document. This document lines can span multiple lines.
 This is another line.

*** title:
 2. PROCESS
*** paragraphs:

 This is a test process. This is another line.

*** title:
 3. ANOTHER HEADING
```

You may wish to remove the newlines before and after the paragraphs.